# python tkinter full frame vs message box focus

Tags: python, focus, tkinter, python-3.2

I am creating a full-frame (no decorations) window with code like this (in python 3.2 using tkinter):

```
self.root = Tk()    
self.W, self.H = self.root.winfo_screenwidth(), self.root.winfo_screenheight()
self.root.overrideredirect(1) # full screen, no menu or borders
self.root.geometry("%dx%d+0+0" % (self.W, self.H))
```

When I try to open a file dialog or message box, they appear UNDER the full frame window.  I can verify this by calling a withdraw() on the main window before I open one of the dialogs. For example,

```
   file = tkinter.filedialog.askopenfilename(parent=self.root) # UNDER main window
```

On windows I don't have a problem with this, only on fedora 14 and ubuntu 12.04 have I noticed it.  (I haven't tested on Mac).  I'm passing a parent to the dialogs but they don't seem to be paying attention.  Can someone help me understand what I'm doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling `.overrideredirect(1)` on a window has a different meanings on Windows and X11. On Windows, it tells the OS to disable drawing of the window border. On X11, it tells the window manager to completely ignore the window. Realistically, it should have the same effect on Windows that it does on X11, but this is not the case.

The reason why calling `.overrideredirect(1)` causes the window to stay on top is because X11 does not have any control over it (as the displaying of the window is not handled by the window manager). The program window and the window manager are completely independent, so implementing standard window stacking would not make sense.

With only tkinter, there is nothing you can do to prevent this behaviour, because tkinter is not really the source of the problem. There may be a way to use X11 Python bindings to show the window without a frame, but this would result in platform specific code.

You may want to rethink removing the window border. Is there a possible alternative? A fullscreen window including the window border is a fine option. Removing window borders is not a good idea at the best of times due to accessibility reasons (no way to move, minimize, maximize, etc.). Also, personally, as a Linux user, I have my window borders customized with all kinds of features (e.g. window tabbing, shade button), and use them quite frequently. Removing the window border would prevent such features from being used.

Comment: With a sad heart and no way of confirming or denying your answer, I will mark it as correct.